# A list of generics with different, but internally consistent type parameters

Tags: typescript, generics

I am currently creating an interface that represents a configuration for a display of an attribute. This is what I’ve got:

```js
interface DisplayConfig<ObjT, ValueT> {
  label: string,
  formatter: (value: ValueT) => string,
  getter: (obj: ObjT) => ValueT,
}
```

The `getter` is a function used to retrieve the value and the `formatter` takes that value and turns it into a human-readable form.

Now I want to type an array of these configs:

```js
interface AttributeTableProps<> {
  rows: DisplayConfig<Plan, any>[]
}
```

The problem is, that when I try to instantiate the above object like this:

```js
const a: AttributeTableProps = {
  rows: [{
    label: "Additional storage per pu",
    getter: (plan) => plan.storage,
    formatter: {memoryFormatter}
  }],
}
```

I get an error, because my `memoryFormatter` only knows how to format `Memory` values. A value of type `Memory` is kept in `plan.storage`, but TypeScript wants a formatter able to render `any`.

My question is: how can I create the types as intended. I want every single item in my array to be “internally consistent” (i.e. the `formatter` being able to accept as an argument the result of the `getter`), but at the same table — allow the rows to operate on different `ValueT`.

Comment: Seems like what I need are “existential types”, which are missing in TypeScript. I will do a workaround, while I mark this as a duplicate of a similar question

Comment: If you know upfront your `TValue` see this https://catchts.com/callbacks#callback_in_union%202